# Access publish outside of SwingWorker

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I am having trouble figuring out a way to call `publish()` and/or `setProgress()` when my time-consuming code is in a method that is not contained within the `SwingWorker`.

To illustrate:

```
class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void process(List<Void> chunks) {
        // Process
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        getData(this);
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void done() {
        // Done.
    }
}

public Object[][] getData(SwingWorker worker) {
    worker.publish(); // <-- publish() is protected, unavailable from outside.
    worker.setProgress(1); // <-- same with setProgress().
    return new Object[0][0];
}
```

This code throws a compiler error because `publish()` and `setProgress()` are protected, and thus inaccessible even if you have the object.

Are there any workarounds to this? It would be unfortunate if everything needed to be contained inside the `SwingWorker` to be published. My `getData()` task is very time-consuming and I'd like to update the user on what's happening.

Hope this question makes sense.

Comment: just repeating (for anybody not reading the longish comments in the answer :-) - it's the setup that needs to be restructured: a SwingWorker isn't meant to be polled from the "outside", it's very strictly a dont-call-us-we-call-you class. Any trick to access it at arbitrary times will lead to constraint violations, thus producing extremely brittle software.

Comment: BTW: would be more productive to describe and ask about your _real_ requirement, not about the problems you have with a perceived solution.

Comment: Noted. But, most of my questions get downvoted and unanswered if I don't show progress towards a solution. My theory is that the solution, at least, helps illustrate the problem. Honestly, I've found that the easiest way to ask a question is to put forth an illustrative answer. I guess that's just how my brain communicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always give your SwingWorker class public methods that other classes may call. These may be as simple as just a wrapper method for one of the protected methods:

```
public void mySetProgress(int progress) {
  super.setProgress(progress);
}
```

---

**A much better way:**
Another way is to re-think your program structure -- have your object with the `getData(...)` method return interim results that the SwingWorker can listen for via some sort of observing mechanism, and then have the worker call its publish method as needed.

---

**Edit 2**
You state in comment:

> Both are solutions I thought about but they both seem to have unfortunate consequences. My getData() method has about 20 steps that I'd like to publish through. Making a program structure that returns interim results would require me to break it up into smaller methods and pass along the results to each method.. Just seems like too much work =/

No, no extra methods are needed. All your getData(...) method needs to do is to periodically update a class property and notify listeners. The listeners (here your SwingWorker) could then extract the class property and call publish with it.

Comment: darn, wrong comment (overlooked the wrapper, sorry ;-) Anyway, not a good idea, the last paragraph describes how to solve it correctly.

Comment: @kleopatra: thanks for your comment. Yeah, the second recommendation seems much stronger to me as it allows the model to be ignorant of the control, and that's a very good thing.

Comment: Both are solutions I thought about but they both seem to have unfortunate consequences. My `getData()` method has about 20 steps that I'd like to publish through. Making a program structure that returns interim results would require me to break it up into smaller methods and pass along the results to each method.. Just seems like too much work =/

Comment: @ryvantage: no, no extra methods are needed. All your `getData(...)` method needs to do is to periodically update a class property and notify listeners. The listeners (here your SwingWorker) could then extract the class property and call publish with it.

Comment: @ryvantage ehh .. this seems to get a bit into the wrong direction: the worker is not meant to listen to anything external - instead let the worker control the external work: it's sole responsibility is to make the communication between from the background thread (that is the getData()) to the EDT - do it in the worker's doInBackground and be safe. You must restructure your setup.

Comment: @kleopatra, the reason the `getData()` method exists is because the same method is called from multiple `SwingWorker`s throughout the program. So performing all of it within the `SwingWorker` isn't an option. With HCFOE's option #1, I could create a generic `SwingWorker` (say, `MySwingWorker`) with a `mySetProgress()` method that each instance of `MySwingWorker` overrides. And then pass the `MySwingWorker` object to each `getData()` method. Why is this not a clean approach?

Comment: I don't know, @kleopatra. I haven't fully implemented it yet but this seeeeems like a good idea to me heh :) I just did this:
`public abstract class VSwingWorker<T, V> extends SwingWorker<T, V> {
    public abstract void updateProgress();
}`
and changed my `Task` to extend `VSwingWorker` instead of `SwingWorker` and now I'm going to accept `VSwingWorker` as an argument in the method. I think this is legit, but I'm open to being proved wrong.

Comment: @ryvantage each caller will violate the wrapped methods precondition ... Hover, I would suggest you remove that wrapping not-a-solution: methods are final with limited scope for a reason. Simply widening the scope is syntactical possible, but does nothing to the reason (aka: outside users can't comply to preconditions)

Comment: Ok I'll rework it. Honestly, when I first wrote this code was years ago when I didn't know any better so I was updating the GUI by passing the GUI as a parameter to my `getData()` method and just updating it on the background thread. :) So anything is better than the way I was doing it.